# Does auto-implemented properties conflict with passing data to a constructor?

Tags: c#, properties

When I construct the Book object (book1), I passed the parameter values to it, but somehow when I tried Console.WriteLine() command, the result did not come up. The screen was just blank.

```
public class Book
{
    private string title;
    private string author;
    private int pages;
    private int wordCount;
    public Book(string title, string author, int pages, int wordCount)
    {
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.pages = pages;
        this.wordCount = wordCount;
    }
    public Book(string title, string author)
    {
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
    }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public int Pages { get; set; }
    public int WordCount { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Book book1 = new Book("Harry Potter", "J. K. Rowling");
        string theTitle = book1.Title;
        Console.WriteLine(theTitle);
    }
}
```

Hey, I'm new to C# and I'm struggling with the concept of properties, especially auto-implemented properties and their relation to constructors.
I made this simple program with two classes, Book and Main. What I want to do is to construct a Book object in the Main class, and ask for the title of the Book object.
When I construct the Book object (book1), I passed the parameter values to it, but somehow when I tried Console.WriteLine() command, the result did not come up. The screen was just blank.
I suspect the problem is calling the getter method (string theTitle = book1.Title;). When I used step in with debug, I see that the variable (title) became null at that line and I don't know why.
I thought book1.Tittle would suppose to "get" the value for me and return it, and then pass it to Console.WriteLine().
Did I miss anything? Please help answer, thanks in advance!

Comment: You are reading and writing to two different properties. while assigning values you assign to `title` and while reading you are using `Title`. Since the value was never assigned to that property, you can not see anything..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare an auto-property it generates its own backing field. But you have declared separate backing fields. This is not necessary. Just set the properties in the constructor.

```
public class Book
{
    public Book(string title, string author, int pages, int wordCount)
    {
        this.Title = title;
        this.Author = author;
        this.Pages = pages;
        this.WordCount = wordCount;
    }
    public Book(string title, string author)
    {
        this.Title = title;
        this.Author = author;
    }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public int Pages { get; set; }
    public int WordCount { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Book book1 = new Book("Harry Potter", "J. K. Rowling");
        string theTitle = book1.Title;
        Console.WriteLine(theTitle);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are creating class instance you are assigning values to the private fields. Not properties. And you are "getting" the property values from the `Main` method. They are essentially empty because you didn't assign them anything.

You can assign values to the "properties" from the constructor:

```
public Book(string title, string author, int pages, int wordCount)
{
    Title = title;
    Author = author;
    Pages = pages;
    WordCount = wordCount;
}
public Book(string title, string author)
{
    Title = title;
    Author = author;
}
```

Now you could get the value from `book1.Title`.

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    Book book1 = new Book("Harry Potter", "J. K. Rowling");
    string theTitle = book1.Title;
    Console.WriteLine(theTitle);
}
```

Also, I suggest you begin the name of private fields with "_":

```
private string _title;
private string _author;
private int _pages;
private int _wordCount;
```

You can find more about the [naming conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/identifier-names) here.